# (Xamarin) pass data from XAML to XAML.cs

Tags: xamarin

I come from a asp.net background, so I have a bit of trouble understanding the whole MVVM idea.

I have a listview, which is filled with messages (it is a sort of forum app). Every message has a button, which, when pressed, should ask the user if they want to delete and then delete when it is confirmed.

I have tried using a Command, but then I get an error (Can you actually call commands to the xaml.cs instead of the ViewModel?) I also tried with an event and a commandparameter, but that also gave me errors.

With Event:
XAML(inside image)

```
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MessageClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding MessageId}"/>
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Code Behind

```
                async void MessageClicked(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
                {
                    string action = "";
        #if __IOS__
                    action = await DisplayActionSheet("Message options", "Cancel", "Delete", "Edit");
        #else
                    action = await DisplayActionSheet("Message options", "Cancel", null, "Edit", "Delete");
        #endif
                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case "Delete":
                            if (await DisplayAlert("Delete message?", "Are you sure you want to delete this message?", "Yes", "No"))
                            {
                                DeleteMessage((int)(e.Parameter));
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Edit":
                            EditMessage((int)(e.Parameter));
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Error: Signature (parameter 1) of EventHandler "XamarinTest.MainPage/_anonXamlCDataTemplate_0.MessageClicked" doesn't match the event type

With Command:
XAML (inside image)

```
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="MessageOptions" CommandParameter="{Binding MessageId}"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Code behind:

```
    public Command<int> MessageOptions
            {
                get { return new Command<int>(i => MessageClickedCommand(i)); }
            }

            async void MessageClickedCommand(int id)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Information", $"The id of this message is: {id}", "Ok");
            }
```

Error:
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Command', or mismatching type between value and property.

In asp.net, I would just attach a data-attribute to the object calling the function, so that the function could retrieve the data itself.
HTML and Javascript would look like:

```
    <div class="functionDiv" data-id="1">
    </div>

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".functionDiv").bind("click", function() {
        var $data = $(this).data("id");
        console.log($data);
      });
    });
```

I want to go to the backend first because there I can call Display functions. Then after that I can go to the ViewModel to do the actual deleting

EDIT
I found a way that works, however it feels dirty

```
    async void MessageClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Converters.GetParameter<int>(sender);
    }

    public static Y GetParameter<Y>(object sender)
    {
        var item = (TapGestureRecognizer)(sender as View).GestureRecognizers[0];    
        return (Y)item.CommandParameter;
    }

    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MessageClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding MessageId}"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Comment: any update? Please give one feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to pass data to .cs using mvvm mode in xamarin.forms, you need tocreate new class inherit Icommand firstly,

```
 public class RelayCommand1: ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then using binding for Button command.

```
  <Button
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.command, Source={x:Reference listview1}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                Text="Delete item" />
```

I create new simple sample for you, you can take a look:

XAML:

```
 <ListView x:Name="listview1" ItemsSource="{Binding persons}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Button
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.command, Source={x:Reference listview1}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                Text="Delete item" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

XAML.cs

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<person> persons { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand1 command { get; set; }

    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        persons = new ObservableCollection<person>();

        for(int i =0;i<20;i++)
        {
            person p = new person()
            {
                Id = i,
                name = "cherry" + i

            };
            persons.Add(p);

            command = new RelayCommand1(obj => method1((int)obj));
        }
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    public void method1(int Id)
    {
        persons.RemoveAt(Id);

    }
}

public class person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```